# Django mptt recursetree with get_cached_trees in template

Tags: python, django, django-mptt

In View:

```
context['categories'] =  = models.Category.objects.all().get_cached_trees()
```

In template:

```
{% load mptt_tags %}
<ul>
    {% recursetree categories %}
        <li>
            {{ node.name }}
            {% if not node.is_leaf_node %}
                <ul class="children">
                    {{ children }}
                </ul>
            {% endif %}
        </li>
    {% endrecursetree %}
</ul>
```

As a result, it renders only first level of queryset. If remove `get_cached_trees` it renders all tree. How to render all tree with `get_cached_trees`?

Answer (score 0):

You don't actually need to call get_cached_trees() in this situation because recursetree already does the caching for you.

From the documentation:

```
Iterates over the nodes in the tree, and renders the contained block for each node.
This tag will recursively render children into the template variable {{ children }}.
Only one database query is required (children are cached for the whole tree)
```